# App crashes only onclick, fatal exception error

Tags: android

Tried many different ways to solve this problem but nothing has worked so far, the error only occurs onclick so Im sure its within my
`orderSummaryTextView_andPrice` but I cant seem to find the issue. Can any of you spot what I did wrong?

Java Main class:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button minusOneButton, plusOneButton, orderButton;
TextView quanityTextView, orderSummaryTextView_andPrice;
CheckBox whipped_cream_check_box, chocolate_checkBox;
EditText user_inputted_name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    minusOneButton = findViewById(R.id.minusOneButton);
    plusOneButton =  findViewById(R.id.plusOneButton);
    orderButton =  findViewById(R.id.orderButton);
    whipped_cream_check_box =  findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_check_box);
    chocolate_checkBox =  findViewById(R.id.chocolate_checkBox);
    user_inputted_name = findViewById(R.id.user_inputted_name);
    quanityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quanityTextView);
    orderSummaryTextView_andPrice = findViewById(R.id.orderSummaryTextView_andPrice);


}

// coffee will cost 1 dollar with an added dollar for each topping

int quanity = 0;

public void submitOrder(View view) {
    calculatePrice();
    createOrderSummery();
}

public void createOrderSummery(){ // titl

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_inputted_name);

    orderSummaryTextView_andPrice.setText(String.valueOf("Name: " + userName.getText().toString() +
            "\nAdd whipped creame? "+ whipped_cream_check_box.isChecked()+
            "\nAdd chocolate? " + chocolate_checkBox.isChecked() +
            "\nQuanity: " + quanity +
            "\nTotal: $" + orderSummaryTextView_andPrice.getText() +
            "\nThank you!")); // creats the summery text onclick
    Log.d("MainActivity.class","Create order summary method finished");
}


public void calculatePrice(){
    int price = Integer.parseInt(orderSummaryTextView_andPrice.getText().toString()); // price = the value of textview 2 in int form
    displayMessage(price); // external method

}
public void displayMessage(int number){
    TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orderSummaryTextView_andPrice); // price = order_summary_text_view
    orderSummaryTextView.setText(String.valueOf(number)); // converted back to a string then displays
}


public void increment(View view) {
    quanity += 1; // this is just a global var
    quanityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(quanity));//we're converting quanity into a string with  the empty quotes so it can be displayed
}

public void decrement(View view) {
    quanity -= 1;
    quanityTextView.setText(String.valueOf(quanity));

}
```

}

Logcat error:

```
2019-01-22 12:37:30.126 23015-23015/com.example.coffee E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.coffee, PID: 23015
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11202)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23969)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11202) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23969) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
    at com.example.coffee.MainActivity.calculatePrice(MainActivity.java:61)
    at com.example.coffee.MainActivity.submitOrder(MainActivity.java:42)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308) 
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11202) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23969) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: ` Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
    at com.example.coffee.MainActivity.calculatePrice(MainActivity.java:61)
    at com.example.coffee.MainActivity.submitOrder(MainActivity.java:42)`

Be sure to safety check your parameter inputs

Comment: int price = Integer.parseInt(orderSummaryTextView_andPrice.getText().toString()); // price = the value of textview 2 in int form here it is an error this will try to value in integer but the textview does not returns an valid integer value in string

Comment: You seem to be a little mixed up as to the intended purpose of the `TextView` with ID `orderSummaryTextView_andPrice`. In `calculatePrice()`, you're trying to get an integer value from it for the price. It's empty there, though, because you've not set any text on it yet, and that's why it's crashing. After the crash line, though, you call `displayMessage()` to show the price in that same `TextView`, with the price that you just tried getting from it. Then, in `createOrderSummery()`, you're setting the whole summary on it, while at the same time getting its own text to use for the `Total: $`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this statement:

```
    int price = Integer.parseInt(orderSummaryTextView_andPrice.getText().toString()); // price = the value of textview 2 in int form
```

in try-catch block to investigate the issue further. This is the only number parsing you are trying to perform in your code and the exception's root cause is a NumberFormatException and you are actually using

> input string: ""

Leave a comment about your investigations and I'll add suggestions to the answer :)